# Getting - weblogic.application.ModuleException - No ComponentMBean was found in Application sample with the URI sample/sampleadapter.rar

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm currently migration our product from J2EE 1.3 to JAVA SE 5. there is a resource adapter called SAMPLEAdapter in our product. I have migrated the ra.xml specific to weblogic to http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector/1.4/weblogic-connector.xsd and  ra.xml to connector_1_5.xsd
After installing the ear when I try to start the ear I get the following error -
weblogic.application.ModuleException: No ComponentMBean was found in Application sample with the URI sample/sampleadapter.rar

at weblogic.application.internal.BaseJ2EEModule.findComponentMBean(BaseJ2EEModule.java:64)
  at weblogic.connector.deploy.ConnectorModule.initAndSetClassLoader(ConnectorModule.java:555)
  at weblogic.connector.deploy.ConnectorModule.init(ConnectorModule.java:532)
  at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:342)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:355)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:383)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
  at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)
  at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(StartOperation.java:95)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doPrepare(StartOperation.java:108)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:233)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1238)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:252)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:172)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
  at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)

Could any one point to me what the exception might be due to ?

Comment: Check your config.xml to ensure that the component MBean is wrapped in a valid application mbean and has a valid URI and Target attribute.

Comment: As of now It got removed due to changes in MDB. I'll get back in case i get into issue again.